# ParseUser JSON response error

Tags: android, json, parse-platform

Im new to Parse and I've tried playing around with Parse a little 
I've stumbled upon an error that I think shouldn't be there
Whenever I declare a new user, and use the

```
signUpInBackground()
```

It returns a bad JSON response error saying that java.lang.String cannot be converted to a JSONObject even though according to the Parse docs, a string should convert to an object
Would anyone help please?
Thank you.!
pic:
[Parse Bad JSON response error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH0gn.png)

Comment: Please add the logcat error.

Comment: I don't know what `parse.com` is but the error means that your `String` is not in a format that can be converted to a `JSONObject`. Perhaps you're missing a comma, bracket etc.

Comment: Here is the error http://i.imgur.com/xHYZlel.jpg.                  I'm using and EditText for input and EditText.getString().toString() which should work since JSON supports Strings

Comment: Are you setting the user name and password in the user object you are creating before calling signUpInBackgroud()? Please show the rest of your code if you want help.

Comment: If you are running this on emulator please show the logcat error so that we can understand the error.

Comment: have you incidentally saved the user before calling signUp?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wfn8ySME .                                     There is the code. Not much to it. I'm not using an emulator. I'm using AIDE so its running directly on my device. I don't think this a syntax error since I've seen it been used many times before. (Also the usernameField and passwordField are both EditText)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the proper app id and client id. The code you posted looks correct.

https://www.parse.com/questions/bad-json-response-on-logincallback

Comment: Oh. It worked. Thank you so much for your help! Sorry for the stupid trouble

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly this again today.
**Check for out of date library references!**

Using Android Studio I was using `compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'` which started giving me "Bad json response" issues when logging a user in.
Changing the parse library to `compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12` fixed this response for me.